# having clause after group by on List<object>

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class RegistryTableItem
{      
  public int Root { get; set; }//assume possible values are 0,1,2,3      
  public string Name { get; set; }     
  public string Component_ { get; set; }
 }

List<RegistryTableItem> _all_RegistryTable_items = //assume you have data in this;

 var result= from regitems in MsiReader._all_RegistryTable_items
             group regitems by regitems.Component_;
             having (root==1 || root==3) && (root==0 || root==2);//fix this line
```

The rule is rootcolumn values in each Componentgroup should be 0,2 or 1,3 (Only these combinations are valid groups). I want items which do not pass this rule.

eg: if a component_x has RegistryTableItems with distinct root values as 1,0 or 2,3 or 1,2,3 etc it should come in the result since they are not part of the valid 2 groups.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. You're grouping by component - a group doesn't have a single root value, it has many RegistryTableItem values. If you can express your requirement more clearly, I'm sure it'll be feasible to express it with a `where` clause. Ideally, show sample input and desired output.

Comment: As an aside: "The rule is rootcolumn values in each Componentgroup should be 0,2 or 1,3..." You need to change the logic in your code, near your `having` statement, to match that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var r = from regitems in MsiReader._all_RegistryTable_items
        group regitems by regitems.Component_ into groupedItems
        where !(groupedItems.Select(i => i.Root).Distinct()
            .OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(new[] { 1, 3 })
        || groupedItems.Select(i => i.Root).Distinct()
            .OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(new[] { 0, 2 }))
        select groupedItems;
```

*Note: There is no direct `having` clause in Linq, you should use `where` instead.*

Comment: Thanks @Alex for solution. But as stated i want 'items which do not pass this rule.' Can i get it directly using the LINQ query?

Comment: @dasariramacharanprasad, please check if the updated code solves your problem.